# Стала вдруг вылетать Java программа под Android Studio + странности

Tags: java, android-studio

Вопроса будет два: как вернуть последнюю "стадию" программы и второй, САМЫЙ важный: как сделать чтобы перестали вылетать сохранённые (рабочие этапы) моей программы.

История болезни:

Делал программу фото и видео съёмки (большая, зараза) с использованием Surface. И всё было прекрасно, но во время очередного Run'a вышло сообщение по середине экрана (серенькое, без красного, я даже не стал читать, а просто проигнорировал, что там было - теперь загадка). За время предпоследнего запуска я просто ковырялся в If'е, т.е. ничего вроде(?) не нажимал, разве нечаянно.

И началось: При запуске на телефоне (USB отладка) сразу выводилось стандартное сообщение об ошибке приложения, другой телефон не решил проблемы. Но теперь и ранее сохранённые рабочие версии этой моей программы не запускались! Но и это ещё не всё, при перезапуске программы Android самым чудесным образом вернул меня в далёкое прошлое состояние программы, после которого я успешно Run'ил десятки раз. 0_0 Т.е. моя довольно большая программа опять вернулась в начало! Всё? Нет, не всё. По ходу постройки программы я многократно копировал всю паку проекта, и вот последние 5 папок имеют одинаково содержание и размер не смотря на то, что при запуске AS открывал последнюю версию. =) В Lokal History --> Show History нет ничего после того момента куда меня "перебросило".

Покопавшись в программе я обнаружил проблемные строки (которые ранее работали прекрасно). Это:

1. camera = Camera.open(); в методе onResume
2. и

   ```
   camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
   camera.setPreviewCallback(this);
   ```

   в методе surfaceCreated
3. Устранение заголовка requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Далее скопировал мои Error логи.

```
05-22 20:42:11.060 1775-1957/? E/AsyncOpDispatcher: Unable to get current module info in ModuleManager created with non-module Context
05-22 20:42:11.282 1550-28437/? E/SeTransactionSyncTask: Error retrieving account
                                                         java.lang.IllegalStateException: No current tap-and-pay account
  at alty.b(:com.google.android.gms@12685021@12.6.85 (040306-197041431):3)
  at alty.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685021@12.6.85 (040306-197041431):1)
  at amnv.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685021@12.6.85 (040306-197041431):28)
  at com.google.android.gms.tapandpay.gcmtask.TapAndPayGcmTaskChimeraService.b(:com.google.android.gms@12685021@12.6.85 (040306-197041431):1)
  at com.google.android.gms.tapandpay.gcmtask.TapAndPayGcmTaskChimeraService.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685021@12.6.85 (040306-197041431):1)
  at com.google.android.gms.tapandpay.phenotype.PhenotypeCommitIntentOperation.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms@12685021@12.6.85 (040306-197041431):47)
  at com.google.android.chimera.IntentOperation.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms@12685021@12.6.85 (040306-197041431):2)
  at dbn.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685021@12.6.85 (040306-197041431):8)
  at nam.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685021@12.6.85 (040306-197041431):9)
  at dbs.run(:com.google.android.gms@12685021@12.6.85 (040306-197041431):10)
  at dbp.run(:com.google.android.gms@12685021@12.6.85 (040306-197041431):9)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
05-22 20:42:12.154 1508-28627/? E/OpaEligibilityChecker: Updating xpromo flags, clock app not present.
05-22 20:42:12.783 1550-28624/? E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
05-22 20:42:13.195 1550-2341/? E/aghj: Phenotype API error. Event
  a <
     a: "LOCAL.com.google.android.agsa.QSB"
     b: 0
     e: ""
     f: ""
     g: 0
     h: 0
     i: ""
     j: 3
   >
   e: # bjyw@f5129a56
   , EventCode: 7 -- metadata{ service_id: 51 }
 aggc: 29505: No config packages for log source, or config package not registered
  at aghv.b(:com.google.android.gms@12685021@12.6.85 (040306-197041431):4)
  at aghj.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685021@12.6.85 (040306-197041431):40)
  at aghj.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685021@12.6.85 (040306-197041431):108)
  at oqt.run(:com.google.android.gms@12685021@12.6.85 (040306-197041431):40)
  at azva.run(:com.google.android.gms@12685021@12.6.85 (040306-197041431):2)
  at ovb.run(:com.google.android.gms@12685021@12.6.85 (040306-197041431):27)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
  at pbc.run(:com.google.android.gms@12685021@12.6.85 (040306-197041431))
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

05-22 20:42:13.196 1550-2341/? E/AsyncOperation: serviceID=51, operation=GetExperimentTokensOperationCall
                                                 OperationException[Status{statusCode=No config packages for log source, or config package not registered, resolution=null}]
  at aghj.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685021@12.6.85 (040306-197041431):53)
  at aghj.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685021@12.6.85 (040306-197041431):108)
  at oqt.run(:com.google.android.gms@12685021@12.6.85 (040306-197041431):40)
  at azva.run(:com.google.android.gms@12685021@12.6.85 (040306-197041431):2)
  at ovb.run(:com.google.android.gms@12685021@12.6.85 (040306-197041431):27)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
  at pbc.run(:com.google.android.gms@12685021@12.6.85 (040306-197041431))
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

05-22 20:42:18.644 28640-28640/? E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
05-22 20:42:21.170 808-3432/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(4)
05-22 20:42:21.173 808-3432/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(4)
05-22 20:42:21.173 808-3432/? E/Sensors: new setDelay handle(4),ns(1000000)m, error(0), index(5)
05-22 20:42:21.181 1927-1927/? E/CellLocation: create GsmCellLocation
05-22 20:42:21.244 1927-1927/? E/SensorManager: sensor or listener is null
05-22 20:42:21.480 808-841/? E/PROXIMITY: ProximitySensor: unknown event (type=3, code=0)
05-22 20:42:21.480 808-841/? E/PROXIMITY: ProximitySensor: unknown event (type=3, code=0)
05-22 20:42:23.278 808-1524/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(4)
05-22 20:42:36.276 808-1330/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(4)
05-22 20:42:36.282 808-1330/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(4)
05-22 20:42:36.282 808-1330/? E/Sensors: new setDelay handle(4),ns(1000000)m, error(0), index(5)
05-22 20:42:36.330 1927-1927/? E/CellLocation: create GsmCellLocation
05-22 20:42:36.590 808-841/? E/PROXIMITY: ProximitySensor: unknown event (type=3, code=0)
05-22 20:42:36.590 808-841/? E/PROXIMITY: ProximitySensor: unknown event (type=3, code=0)
05-22 20:42:36.769 1927-1927/? E/SensorManager: sensor or listener is null
05-22 20:42:38.897 808-2544/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(4)
05-22 20:42:51.241 808-819/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(4)
05-22 20:42:51.246 808-819/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(4)
05-22 20:42:51.247 808-819/? E/Sensors: new setDelay handle(4),ns(1000000)m, error(0), index(5)
05-22 20:42:51.332 1927-1927/? E/CellLocation: create GsmCellLocation
05-22 20:42:51.549 808-841/? E/PROXIMITY: ProximitySensor: unknown event (type=3, code=0)
05-22 20:42:51.550 808-841/? E/PROXIMITY: ProximitySensor: unknown event (type=3, code=0)
05-22 20:42:51.703 1927-1927/? E/SensorManager: sensor or listener is null
05-22 20:42:53.732 808-2543/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(4)
05-22 20:43:06.266 808-3434/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(4)
05-22 20:43:06.271 808-3434/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(4)
05-22 20:43:06.271 808-3434/? E/Sensors: new setDelay handle(4),ns(1000000)m, error(0), index(5)
05-22 20:43:06.323 1927-1927/? E/CellLocation: create GsmCellLocation
05-22 20:43:06.584 808-841/? E/PROXIMITY: ProximitySensor: unknown event (type=3, code=0)
05-22 20:43:06.584 808-841/? E/PROXIMITY: ProximitySensor: unknown event (type=3, code=0)
05-22 20:43:06.831 1927-1927/? E/SensorManager: sensor or listener is null
05-22 20:43:08.900 808-1330/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(4)
05-22 20:43:21.178 808-1330/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(4)
05-22 20:43:21.180 808-1330/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(4)
05-22 20:43:21.180 808-1330/? E/Sensors: new setDelay handle(4),ns(1000000)m, error(0), index(5)
05-22 20:43:21.186 1927-1927/? E/CellLocation: create GsmCellLocation
05-22 20:43:21.264 1927-1927/? E/SensorManager: sensor or listener is null
05-22 20:43:21.490 808-841/? E/PROXIMITY: ProximitySensor: unknown event (type=3, code=0)
05-22 20:43:21.490 808-841/? E/PROXIMITY: ProximitySensor: unknown event (type=3, code=0)
05-22 20:43:23.304 808-3432/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(4)
```

Очень надеюсь на помощь!

Comment: 1) Как понял проблема была в конфликте запуска USB программы и установленного через apk этой же. Но устранить проблему я смог только на другом компьютере, где вышла та же ошибка, но с сообщением о каком-то удалении. Я согласился, ещё что то поделал (включая повторные разрешения в настройках "программы" телефона) и вуаля. Хотя простое удаление программы с телефона и отладкой по USB результатов не давало как и создание нового проекта с перекопированием из старого. 2) Да, последние 5 сохранений в отдельных папках имели одинаковый размер! Теперь сохраняю Активити в вёрде и ВК. Никому не верю! )

Answer (score 1):

Дам вам ясность в ответе как вернуть данные .Чтобы не случилось таких случаев пользуйтесь системами контроля версий в простонародье репозиториями туда кладете код и берете если грубо.к примеру Git ,SVN